# Is it possible to make tfoot appear above tbody within the same table?

Tags: jquery, html

I am working around a limitation of using a jquery plugin and rendering my table according to the standards, i.e. thead, tfoot and tbody in that order. The browser then correctly renders it, and makes the tfoot appear below the tbody as is supposed to do. Is there a hack/straight forward way to make the tfoot appear and render above the tbody as well?

Comment: did you try with `position:absolute;` (then move it where you want) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mess around with absolute positioning of the `tfoot` and `tbody` elements.  I'm not sure how it works cross-browser and you need to know the positions.  But here's an example:

```
table {
    position: relative;
}
tfoot {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}

tbody {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YJhk2/

Answer (score 19):

Something sounds wrong to me, but you can change the `display` type of the `tfoot`

```
tfoot {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/UMZr4/